# Formula required for recoding in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Say I have the following table (VAR stands for variable):#

```
VAR1 VAR2  VAR3  VAR4    OUT 
 1     1     1     1    VAR4
 0     1     1     0    VAR3
 1     0     0     0    VAR1
 1     1     0     0    VAR2
```

Thus, each variable is coded in 1 or 0.
VAR4 is weighted greater than VAR3, VAR3 is weighted greater than VAR2, etc.

If only one VAR is 1, then that VAR is given in the output.
However, if more than one VAR are 1, then the output is only the VAR with highest weight,
i.e., if VAR2 and VAR4 are 1, all other 0, then output column would be VAR4.

What would the input formula in Excel for this be, or is there any quick way of doing it?

Comment: The table did not come out as planned as it should read                 VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4 OUT *new line* etc. Apologies

Comment: No, unfortunately I have never learnt VBA. What would the code be in VBA? And can i then input this into excel some how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say to put in E7 :

```
="VAR" & IF(D7=1,4,IF(C7=1,3,IF(B7=1,2,IF(A7=1,1,0))))
```

where A is the column of VAR1, B of VAR2, C of VAR3 and D of VAR4.
Just place the formula inside the column E
(check the indices ; the formula above is for the line number 7 (E7))

Comment: Would I not place the formula in column E?

Comment: Yes, you want to place it under OUT which is E indeed ;p

Comment: Perfect thanks! I'll give it a try there now and see how it goes! Thanks!

Comment: However there is a particular case when all variables are null ; the formula I gave will write VAR0 (is this what is expected?). 
If that answered your question though, don't forget to check solved ;p

Comment: When I try and input it into excel it says there is an error in the formula?

Comment: The message is "The formula you typed contains and error". I typed it exactly into excel as is there?

Comment: It's probably the list separator ';' try to replace them with ','

Comment: I'm sorry but I feel this is the WORST answer of posted answers. While yes it does solve THIS EXACT issue. It is unhelpful for future readers who don't have a Word + INDEX naming scheme and need a dynamic way of returning the column header. It returns incorrect information if the condition aren't met. And if in the future if any of the Data changes, Var Names are added, It will require more and more nested if statements to accommodate that, on top of the fact it will simply not work if headers are changed. If then Data shifts columns, it can get messy to re-write all of it again.

Answer (score 1):

The following array formula will get the job done. Note that it does not require that the VAR names be of the form VAR + number, i.e., it will choose the desired name from those in the first row of the data columns.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$D$1,1,IF(SUM(A5:D5)=0,1/0,MAX({1,2,3,4}*A2:D2))),"-")
```

The ISERROR and 1/0 trap the case where all the weights are zero and return a "-" instead of a VAR name. If the case of all zero weights will not occur, then the formula simplifies to:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$D$1,1,MAX({1,2,3,4}*A2:D2))
```

This formula would be entered in cell E2 and copied down. Since it is an array formula, it should be entered with the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is at the beginning of the sheet, use this formula:

```
=IF(D2=1,$D$1,IF(C2=1,$C$1,IF(B2=1,$B$1,IF(A2=1,$A$1,0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This formula will work as your data grows and allow a little more flexability:

```
=LOOKUP(TRUE,1/$A2:$D2=1,$A$1:$D$1)
```

A2:D2=1 returns an Array of TRUE/FALSE of each column if it contains `1`
1/A2:D2=1 will reverse that array
finding TRUE in the reverse array will return the position that had the First (or last because it is reversed) match that was TRUE, and use the header in that position.

This Formula ***DOES NOT*** need to be array entered, you can enter it as a normal formula

If all weights are 0 the formula will return `#N/A`